# Should I encapsulate collection also in a setter?

Tags: java, collections, encapsulation, setter

Should I replace a simple setter

```
public void setCategories(Set<String> categories)
{
    this.categories = categories;
}
```

with something like this:

```
public void setCategories(Collection<String> categories)
{
    this.categories.clear();
    if (categories != null)
    {
        this.categories.addAll(categories);
    }
}
```

so object's attribute categories won't be further modifiable through passed parameter reference as it could be:

```
Set<String> categories = new TreeSet<String>();
categories.add("cityguide");
categories.add("other");
Document document = new Document("http://unique-address.com");
document.setCategories(categories);
System.out.println(categories); //outputs [cityguide, other]
System.out.println(document.getCategories()); //outputs [cityguide, other]
document.setCategories(categories);
categories.add("traveling");
System.out.println(categories); //outputs [cityguide, other, traveling]
System.out.println(document.getCategories()); //outputs [cityguide, other, traveling]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, yes you should

another option is also making a new set for the field in the setter but your solution is better as it avoid the (unnecessary) allocation

or remove and add each category in a loop

```
public void setCategories(Collection<String> categories)
{
    for(String cat:this.category.toArray(new String[0])){//using toArray to avoid ConcurrentModificationException
        removeCategory(cat);
    }
    if (categories != null)
    {
        for(String cat:categories){
            addCategory(cat);
        }
    }
}
```

so you won't have to duplicate any triggers for removing and/or or adding a category

Answer (score 0):

So , all you want to do  is just add a string collection to the `Document`  's `categories` .

I will  just create the following methods to do it :

```
public void addCategory(String categories){
             this.categories.add(categories);
}

public void addCategory(Collection<String> categories){
         this.categories.addAll(categories);
}
```

So ,if I want the `Document`  's `categories` set won't be further modified through passed parameter reference , I will use the `addCategory()` .

If I want the `Document`  's `categories`  can be further modified  through passed parameter reference , I can still use the original `setCategories()`